do I need to hold ETH (for tokens) in my wallet to receive ERC-20 with value?
I want to receive ETH (ERC-20) which was initially converted from BTC to ETH and sent to my wallet with 0 value.
Do I need to hold ETH in my wallet in order to activate ETH tokens to receive real ETH value? Thank you in advance for answers!

Ether isn't a token ERC-20. There is the popular WETH that is a token wrapping Ether in a contract, and ethers could be extracted by calling the withdraw function from the contract. An ERC-20 named ETH it is dubious, it could be a scam. Can you provide more details about the token?

Hi Ismael, as I'm going through recovery process from my blockchains I will appreciate if you can contact me directly on facebook (https://www.facebook.com/jacek.per) to advise if I'm not going through scam. I will appreciate your help as now I'm going through mirror transactions https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cics-ts/5.6?topic=shipping-mirror-transaction-transformer-program and I don't know whether I can trust what I hear. talk to you soon!

Ismael. let me add a sentence from communication related to recovery and comment that I do have cold wallet in Atomic and hot wallet in Kraken, and I'm asked to hold money in Kraken (as there were not transactions and needs verification) in order to allow mirror transaction flow - does it makes sense in withdraw (recovery) process?

Sentence: "As soon as the exact amount you need to have on your Kraken account, the system will start the mirror transaction through the Blockchain - to your Cold Wallet, and from there you will have to move it yourself into your Kraken account. When it arrives to the Kraken you'll need to sell the Bitcoins for Euros and the Euros you will be able to make a bank transfer to your bank" - does it make sense?

Sorry, but I'll only reply here. There's nothing like mirror transactions on the ethereum blockchain. I highly suspect that you have been scammed.

thank you Ismael!

hi @higger Did you do what the recovery team asked? My recovery agent is also asking me to deposit $1000 worth of ETH to transfer out the recovered funds.
I tried to contact you in facebook but no reply. Please reply me

Hi @Ismael What I mentioned above, is it legit?

@GaneshKumar That is a red flag. No serious recovery company ask for money in advance. They usually discount their fees from the recovered funds.

@Ismael They didnt charge me upfront. They have recovered the fund as ERC20 tokens. I have transferred the ERC-20 tokens from atomic wallet to my personal wallet but I cant see the ERC20 tokens reflected in my personal wallet. After some research, I found out that the tokens were a part of smart contract. Now the recovery agent is telling me that only when I deposit $1000 worth of ETH to the atomic wallet then the funds will be reflected in my personal wallet. What do you know about smart contract? How can you check whether this is a real token?

@GaneshKumar Why they would recover the funds and send them to a smart contract? Why they would send you a useless token until you send them money? Can you share the contract and source code? Is it a public company? For me all those unnecessary steps are red flags.

@Ismael they are a public company in the UK, London. This is their registration proof https://find-and-update.company-information.service.gov.uk/company/16009753
Their website is https://fiordintel.net/
This is the token and it has the contract link https://etherscan.io/token/0xd9D0F29C4C2a8919639F989d32927bC3b4db9c09?a=0x8f542183ac51949acfabdc30dad801cef124e865
Is there a way I can contact you other than here? It takes a day to have a two way communication between us. facebook? twitter? whatsapp?

I only answer here on my free time. From the provided registry entry the company is less than 2 months old. The token has no value. It is a kinda of flag that they had used "ETH" as token name, and 21,000,000 as their supply. On their site they claim 10 years of experience but they provide no names of their founders. Another red flag is that their blog has the default "hello world" post from wordpress https://fiordintel.net/hello-world/. C'mon.

@Ismael thank you for your help. I have told him that I wont pay a single penny. Also asked him why he's deposited as a smart contract. He's not ready to meet my friend in his office as well. So I've decided to not to do this. Thanks again for your help

No, you don't need any ETH, but you'll need ETH if you want to transfer them from your wallet.

Thank you Adam for your valuable comment! Can it be that funds are on hold (blocked with Fake_Phishing alerts as they have 0 value) in the ETH network and they require to have legitimacy to have a value on the ERC-20 and therefore need ETH tokens - does it make sense?  if I would like to transfer ETH from my wallet do I need to keep additional ETH (around 10% of value which I want to send)? - does it sound reasonable?
